# How do I create a constant in Snap?

Tags: snap-lang

How can I create a constant in the Snap! programming language?

Answer (score 2):

I use a custom reporter block that returns a single value.

1. Change to the Variables palette
2. Select "Make a block"
3. Name your constant, select "Reporter", and click OK

[image]

4. Enter the constant value in the report block and click OK

[image]

5. Insert the new block wherever you would like to use the constant

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to know the purpose of the constant.

If you are comfortable with creating a constant global variable, it may be slightly easier than the above method:

1. Choose the "Variables" palette.
2. Choose "Make a Variable."
3. Directly below this variable, select "Set _ to 0" and set this constant variable to the desired value. You can use this variable wherever (same as above).